# How to add HTML to an existing PDF using iText

Tags: html, pdf, itext

I have a PDF file that contains a form. I need to fill this form using iText then parse an HTML string and add its content at the bottom of the page (content may overflow so a new page must be created)

I figured out how to fill the form using this code

```
PdfReader pdfTemplate = new PdfReader("rapport.pdf");
File file = new File("out.pdf");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfTemplate, fileOutputStream);
AcroFields form = stamper.acroFields;
form.setGenerateAppearances(true);
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
form.setField("code", code);
stamper.close();
pdfTemplate.close();
fileOutputStream.close();
```

I know that there exists this function to convert html to pdf

```
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml();
```

But this will generate another document not append the html string at the bottom of the first page

Comment: Where should it append? There is no marker in a PDF indicating "filled up to here"...

Comment: ok I see, so there is now way to add the parsed html at the end of the existing pdf because itext does not know where it ends

Comment: You could try to determine such an end position and left and right margins, e.g. by parsing the page and determining the bounding box of existing content and comparing it to the crop box of the page. Then you can add the elements returned by the `XMLWorker` in that area using a `ColumnText` instance.